# Objective-C inheritance; calling overridden method from superclass?

Tags: objective-c, oop, inheritance

I have an Objective-C class that has a method that is meant to be overridden, which is uses in a different method. Something like this:

```
@interface BaseClass
- (id)overrideMe;
- (void)doAwesomeThings;
@end

@implementation BaseClass
- (id)overrideMe {
    [self doesNotRecognizeSelector:_cmd];
    return nil;
}
- (void)doAwesomeThings {
    id stuff = [self overrideMe];
    /* do stuff */
}
@end

@interface SubClass : BaseClass
@end

@implementation SubClass
- (id)overrideMe {
    /* Actually do things */
    return <something>;
}
@end
```

However, when I create a `SubClass` and try to use it, it still calls `overrideMe` on the `BaseClass` and crashes due to `doesNotRecognizeSelector:`. (I'm not doing a `[super overrideMe]` or anything stupid like that).

Is there a way to get `BaseClass` to call the overridden `overrideMe`?

Comment: Just to make sure if I'm understanding correctly, you're calling `[subclassInstance overrideMe]` and it crashes due to a `doesNotRecognizeSelector:`? Sounds a little bit strange, but if I were you, the first thing I would check is to see if I spelled the name of the method correctly when overriding (if you misspell the name of the method in your implementation, the compiler won't complain, and when you call the correct method name, it won't have been overridden)...

Answer (score 2):

What you are describing here should work so your problem is likely elsewhere but we don't have enough information to help diagnose it.

From your description, I'd say either the instance you're messaging is not the class you think it is or you made some typo in your code when declaring the method names.

Run your application under gdb, add a symbolic breakpoint on objc_exception_throw, reproduce your problem. Once your process has stopped on the "doesNotRecognizeSelector" exception, print object description and it's class.

Or log it before calling -overrideMe:

NSLog(@"object: %@ class: %@", obj, [obj class])

Comment: This was good advice. I ended up using a protocol though, which actually was better suited for this particular case, but thanks!

Comment: @AnshuChimala Don't forget to accept the answer, if this question is solved.

Answer (score -1):

Write a category for `BaseClass` to override the method.

```
@interface BaseClass (MyCategory)
- (id) overrideMe;
@end

@implementation BaseClass (MyCategory)
- (id) overrideMe
{
    /* Actually do things */    
    return <something>;
}

@end
```

Now all instances of `BaseClass` will respond to selector `overrideMe` with the new implementation.

Comment: This is a very bad advice: trick Objective C because you did not find why your code is (apparently) not working the way it should.